# get route name from url with subdomain in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I can get router name by url with this snippet:

```
$url = myproject.com/test/new

$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);

$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

$router = $fontController->getRouter();

$router->route($request);

$router->getCurrentRouteName(); // Here I can get a router name
```

This works for me when I have an url without subdomain. But with url like "mysubdomain.myproject.com/test/new" I can't get a right router name. But when I open this url in browser it renders right controller and action. To add routes (Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname) like "mysubdomain.myproject.com/test/new" I use chain() method.
So, how can I get a right router name?

Comment: Have you tried using relative urls (/test/new)?

Comment: Yes, and I get exception "Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted". Zend_Controller_Request_Http wants url with schema (e.g. "http").